# PHP + Laravel | guzzlehttp/guzzle HTTP Client Cache Invalidation / refresh

Tags: php, laravel, caching, httpclient, guzzle

## Question

How can I programmatically tell to a Guzzle Client to **delete / eliminate or refresh a Cache folder?**

An even better, to target a specific folder **X** or **Y**?

The reason is not important, but I can put an example for better understand.
Let's say we have book api (which is mine) an with another service we call it with Guzzle Client and has a cache of *1 hour* to get some book prices. The cache is at folder

`framework/cache/data/GuzzleFileCache/public/books/prices`

```
curl -X GET https://example.com/books/prices
```

Now, someone updates the books prices.
If my main service call `books/orices` will have now the old prices because 1 hour was not passed.

So I've a system that when a book price is updated I can fire an event to my main service and tell whatever I want. Unsurprisingly what I want my main service to do is to invalidate the cache at `framework/cache/data/GuzzleFileCache/public/books/prices` when that even if fired.

How can I do that?

### Code

First of all, note to say that I'm actually using [Lumen](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/9.x) but it shouldn't be a problem as works the same as Laravel.

So let's say that I've a specific folder at `framework/cache/data/GuzzleFileCache/public/blogs`  and I need at certain point invalidate this cache (for whatever reason).

*I know you can just delete manually the folder, and therefore probably do it programmatically, **but is there a better way?** *

This is my current code to **create/use the cache** with a Guzzle Client

```
$ttl = 3600;
// Create a HandlerStack
$stack = HandlerStack::create();
// Create Folder GuzzleFileCache inside the providen cache folder path
$requestCacheFolderName = 'framework/cache/data';
// Retrieve the bootstrap folder path of your Laravel Project
$cacheFolderPath = 'GuzzleFileCache/public/blogs';

// Instantiate the cache storage: a PSR-6 file system cache with
$cache_storage = new Psr6CacheStorage(
    new FilesystemAdapter(
        $requestCacheFolderName,
        $ttl,
        $cacheFolderPath
    )
);

// Add Cache Method
$stack->push(
    new CacheMiddleware(
        new GreedyCacheStrategy(
            $cache_storage,
            $ttl // the TTL in seconds
        )
    ),
    'greedy-cache'
);
```

So one very ugly way would be to just delete that folder, here is some pseudocode

```
rmdir('framework/cache/data/GuzzleFileCache/public/blogs');
```

But I'm looking at something like

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http; // <--- laravel guzzle client 

Http::cacheInvalidate('framework/cache/data/GuzzleFileCache/public/blogs');
```

#### Dependencies

```
"php": "^8.1.3",
"flipbox/lumen-generator": "^9.1",
"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.4", 
"kevinrob/guzzle-cache-middleware": "^4.0",
"laravel/lumen-framework": "^9.0",
"symfony/cache": "^6.1"
```

#### References

- [HTTP Client](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-client)
- [Kevinrob/guzzle-cache-middleware](https://github.com/Kevinrob/guzzle-cache-middleware)

Comment: what type of files are there in framework/cache/data/GuzzleFileCache/public/books/prices like extension

Comment: I have no idea. I don't even think there is am extension  . Why ?

Comment: is there a better way? what do you meean by that if you don;t want to delete cache then you can rename it, or do you want to make the deletion dynamic in which you decide which folder t o delete in a non hard coded way

Comment: @bhucho  Yes deleting dynamically or targeted folder I one way and the one that I know. But the purpose of the question is to know if there is a **better implementation or way.** What do I mean?  I mean  a funcionallity of guzzle that I don't know or an existing library,

Comment: I just saw if you are using symfony/cache they have cache tags for latest versions you can use those to invaidate a cache with a particular tag

Comment: @bhucho I give you an example. Let's say you know to echo only in this way: echo "something ". $myvar . " concat";  | comes one collegue an tells you: "Look I have a *better way to do it!*  and it shows you: "something $myvar concat";  So in this case, the **better way* is the fact that you can just put the variable inside the string and it will automatically interporlate.  Or a 'bad practice' typical thing in PHP is put back and and view in the same file <?php $user = $db->users()"; ?> <p> <?= $user ?></p>    . Instead the same collegue comes and tell you. "You can use include"" Got it?

Comment: @bhucho  -> "I just saw if you are using symfony/cache they have cache tags for latest versions you can use those to invaidate a cache with a particular tag"  Have you got any link?

Comment: [this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/cache/cache_invalidation.html) is the link.

Comment: Could be  but I havent found an example usiging guzzle. Is a really obscure feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. I could not invalidate the cache by tags but at least all the cache together, which is already something. Here some code if may help someone.

```
use Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\FilesystemAdapter;
use Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\TagAwareAdapter;

// Instantiate the cache storage: a PSR-6 file system cache with
$cache = new TagAwareAdapter(
// Adapter for cached items
    new FilesystemAdapter(
        $requestCacheFolderName,
        1,
        $cacheFolderPath
    )
);
$cache->clear();
```